# App with an auto-renewable subscription rejected because demo account needed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Apple rejected my app with an :

> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue because we need an expired demo account to fully assess the subscription feature.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide us with a link to a demo account in the App Review Information section of App Store Connect and reply to this message in Resolution Center.

I really don’t understand what kind of demo account they want from me. There are no any login screens in the application. Active subscription needed to access pdf share function.

Should I give them a test sandbox account with which we tested the subscriptions or something else?

Comment: Just comply with what they want. If you really really think they are in the wrong side, prove it and explain properly what they need to do to test your application fully.

Comment: I don't understand what they want. They ask for demo account but there are no any accounts in the app, except subscriptions test sandbox accounts. Should I give them login for sandbox account?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that part. YES, and while providing the sandbox account, explain what you gotta explain.

Comment: Normally you do not need to give them the credentials of your sandbox account (as long as it is possible to subscribe to the subscription within the app). Did you by any chance signal during submission that your app requires a login? There is a checkbox on the page for the app version and during submission apple shows a dialog asking if a login is required.

Comment: @PaulSchröder I don't mark this checkbox. :( If I checked it, I couldn't submit without giving them login and password, so it can't be marked by accident.

Comment: @Glenn I will try, thanks! But I thought that they should have access to sandbox accounts anyway.

Comment: @Soloqub did you managed to solve the problem?